# Matching strings in switch statements

Tags: r, string, switch-statement

I'd like to use a switch statement to branch according to the first two characters of a string. In the example shown below, I'd like to return "Apple" with either "aabb" or "aacc"

```
test<-c("aabb", "aacc", "bbbb")

foo <- Vectorize(function(a) {
      switch(as.character(a),
            "^aa" = "Apple",
            "bbbb" = "Grape",
            "Unknown")

}, "a")

> foo(test)
aabb      aacc      bbbb 
"Unknown" "Unknown"   "Grape"
```

I can get the statement to work if there is an exact match, but I can't figure out how to get a match using only the first two characters. Maybe there is a way using Regex? As shown, I've tried to use  `^` to match the beginning of the string (which works with `grep`) but it doesn't work.

I think I could use nested `ifelse` statements with `grepl` but can it work using `switch`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to manual, this is impossible with `switch` because it only allows exact match:

> switch(EXPR, ...)
>
> If EXPR evaluates to a character string then that string is matched
>   (exactly) to the names of the elements in `...`.

But you can do it with `case_when` in `dplyr`:

```
foo <- function(x){
    dplyr::case_when(
        grepl('^aa', x) ~ 'Apple',
        x == 'bbbb' ~ 'Grape',
        TRUE ~ 'Unknown'
    )
}
foo(test)
# [1] "Apple" "Apple" "Grape"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `substr()` to extract the first two letters; use `setNames()` to propagate the full names rather than abbreviation to the answer

```
> X = setNames(substr(test, 1, 2), test)
> sapply(X, switch, aa="Apple", bb = "Grape", "Unknown")
   aabb    aacc    bbbb 
"Apple" "Apple" "Grape"
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work:

```
regex_switch<-function(.v,...)
{
  e<-enexprs(...)
  i<-min(which(str_detect(.v,names(e))))
  eval(e[[i]],parent.frame())
}
```

```
> map_chr(
   c("aaaa","bb","aabbaa"),
   regex_switch,
   "^aa"="Apple","^bbbb"="Grape","^*$"="Unknown"
)  
[1] "Apple"   "Unknown" "Apple"  
>
```